# Preview images, contours, etc during opencv debug sessions by rendering them on a web page

Tags: image, opencv, debugging, web, mat

Is there any ready-to-use solution to push my image in Mat format to a web service that will display it on a web page instantly?

I'm trying to replace an image preview in a window with some web-based solutions for my debugging sessions.

Answer (score 1):

If you use CLion and C++ you can utilize the OpenCV Image Viewer plugin, which displays matrices while debugging just on click.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14371-opencv-image-viewer

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm an author of this plugin